# How to load data into table view

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

How do I load data into my `UITableView`? Can anyone please kindly help me with this issue:
why not load to cellForRowAt

- pPlandDetailId ==>Optional(1)
- Driver ==> Driver Name:Boonma,Pongpat
- carRegistrtation ==> Car Registrtation:60-7620
- StoreLocation ==> ["S.Surathani"]
- pDepartureDateTime ==> ["18/01/2019 20:00"]

```
import UIKit

class StoreListMainViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

// TableView
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var StoreLocation: [String] = []
    var getDepartureTime: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createTableiew()
    }//Main Method

     //  TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return StoreLocation.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? cellTableViewCell
        cell!.Location.text = StoreLocation[indexPath.row]
        cell!.DepartureTime.text = getDepartureTime[indexPath.row]
        print("cell!.Location.text ==>\(String(describing: cell!.Location.text) )")
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gotoTempMonitorStoreList") as? StoreListTempMonitorViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }

   //  Create UI Table view
    func createTableiew() -> Void {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }//createTableiew
```

```
import UIKit

class cellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var Location: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var DepartureTime: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is you viewdidload did you approve your tableview delegate in it also after you fetching data you should reload your tableView

Comment: From your code, it seems you have multiple problems that may be causing it to not load data. In the `cellForRowAt`, you're setting two values to two labels but the `StoreLocation` array you're using as the data source is just a string array. First, could you tell what's `jsonResponsePlanDetail` and maybe show an example of its structure here?

Comment: @Isuru  I'm update coded please suggest me again

Comment: @Nardanong.s I'm still not seeing what `jsonResponsePlanDetail` is? The name suggests that it is a JSON response. Could you show what it looks like?

Comment: @Isuru I'm updated code and show  jsonResponsePlanDetail already. Please suggest me. why date cannot load to cellForRowAt

Comment: @Isura I can load data into cellForRowAt in TableView completed.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reload tableview `tableView.reload()` where you have received data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using a `UITableViewController` you need to set a delegate and a dataSource to your `tableView` object.
Looks something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      tableView.dataSource = self
      tableView.delegate = self
}
```

That's it. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first fetch the data and later try to reload your table view.
Once you set the array to table values automatically they will get displayed in table provided you code object's properties to cell's Outlet values.